# Are there well known test vectors for quaternions ? known test code that punishes naive implementations?

Tags: go, testing, math, matrix

I want to implement some basic quaternion functions to keep my programming skills honed.

Are there well known test vectors or test values to use?

Long ago, I worked on some matrix inversion code for calculating variances. There is a well known data set that is used to show poor programming practices and limitations of the naive implementations for matrix work based on the work of statistician J.W. Longley. It is a small dataset, easy to use, but really stresses the numerical analysis.  See [Longley data set](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/datasets/generated/longley.html)
Are there equivalent data sets for quaternions?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at some go code on github and combined their test data/vectors into the following quaternion_test.go code
[github quarternion test code](https://github.com/pfarrell51/gows/blob/master/src/github.com/pfarrell51/cmd/quaternion_test.go)